# Are there Frontend Architecture Pattern to follow?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture, frontend

In backend development there are patterns to follow such as an application with models, repos, services and controllers. In the frontend, I have not yet encountered such a pattern. This may be due to the fact that I am a beginner or that no patterns have been established. Are there any basic patterns you can follow to better organize your code? I use Angular and i am missing some Pattern like in the backend development.

Expertise and certainty that certain patterns exist in the frontend to which one can orient oneself. In case there are none, helpful tips on how to optimally structure your frontend application in Angular, for example.

By this I mean, for example, instead of storing all HTTP requests to the backend in the service folder and accessing them in the component (usually subscribing?), create a controller as in the backend and implement a service class where subscribing takes place and only receive the pure data in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, Angular has [the coding style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) where how project can be structured:

- where and how service/pipes/components should be placed and what code should be placed in them. So these are examples of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle) of SOLID.
- how to give name for components. How to apply DRY principle for naming
- where presentation logic should be placed

Besides, it is possible to apply design patterns at the front end too, however, I would believe that the style guide of Angular would be enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses the modular approach and its .ts file work as controller. and yes you can direct do the HTTPS request without using a service but It's a bad approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).